# Accept changes in model with admin in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 3 different types of users in my ASP.Net MVC website: admin, user, company. I want to let the companies change their info but the changes won't be applied until the admin accepts those changes. I was wondering what's the recommended method to achieve such functionality. I was thinking maybe I should  create 2 models for each type (for instance `Company` and `Company_temp` with identical fields and add the info to the temp table whenever the company submits changes. Then read them in the admin account and then apply them back to the real table. Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds perfectly reasonable to me.  The only thing I would possibly change would be to call the second type `CompanyUnapproved`, or `CompanyAwaitingApproval`, something along those lines.  It makes your code more readable and your intentions clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I like both names. I'm not thinking right at 7AM (without sleep of course) :D

Comment: @AlirezaNoori No problem, and I know the feeling. :)